# Position breadcrumbs to the bottom of the header

Tags: html, css, responsive, breadcrumbs

I am trying to position my breadcrumbs and the title of the page to the bottom of the header image.

So I have a hero-image which is an image and the height is 400px. There should be 2 divs in line, one is title on the left and the other one is breadcrumbs should be on the right. But also title and breadcrumbs should be on the buttom so the width is getting smaller comparing to container. I want the width with the same size of container.

```css
.hero-image .hero-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  list-style: none;
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  content: "/\00a0";
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb li a {
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-bottom">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color:#aaa;">
          <h2>Title of the page</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color:#bbb;">
          <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Summer 15</a></li>
            <li>Italy</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have added `width:100%;` in `.hero-bottom` and give `position:relative` to `.container` so width and position of `.hero-bottom` will set with respect to `.container`

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/cxqk3mn0/1/

```css
.hero-image {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-image .container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-image .hero-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  list-style: none;
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  content: "/\00a0";
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb li a {
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-image ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="hero-image" style="background:url('https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/fff');">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-bottom">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color:#aaa;">
          <h2>Title of the page</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color:#bbb;">
          <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Summer 15</a></li>
            <li>Italy</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution.